# How to add GREATER_THAN / LESS_THAN operator to DB query in Zend\Db\Sql?

Tags: sql, database, zend-framework2

I need to add special operators to my query. Query:

```
SELECT "contests".*
FROM "contests" WHERE "status" = '-1' 
AND "level1" = '1' AND "level2" = '1' AND "level3" = '1' AND "level10" = '1' 
AND DATE(`contests`.`start`) >= '2012-03-17' AND DATE(`contests`.`stop`) <= '2013-12-20'
```

In Zend Framework 2:

```
$from = '2012-03-17';
$to = '2013-12-20';
  $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
  $select = $sql->select('contests')
     ->where($where, $combination = new Predicate\Operator($from, Predicate\Operator::OPERATOR_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO, $to));
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about if you write your where clause like this:-

```
$select->where->equalTo('status', '-1'); 
$select->where->equalTo('level1', '1');
```

and etc

```
$select->where->greaterThanOrEqualTo('start', '2012-03-17');
$select->where->greaterThanOrEqualTo('stop', '2013-12-20');
```

Comment: is there a lessThanOrEqualTo function ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using table gateway. It is more clear to use.
you can use where clause.

```
public function getGelecek()
{
    $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
    $select->where(array('active' => '1'));
    $select->where->greaterThan('tarih', '123');
    $resultset = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
    return $resultset;
}
```